# Simson's line proof

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Q. Let $ABC$ be a triangle and P be any point on $(ABC)$. Let
X, Y , Z be the feet of the perpendiculars from P onto lines BC, CA, and AB respectively. Prove that
points $X, Y , Z$ are collinear.

 
 
Actually I started going through the book EGMO and got an alternate proof.But I guess, it's wrong somewhere please check my steps...

Answer-
Extend XY such that it meets AB extended, at Z'

It would be suffice to show that AYPZ' is cyclic.

Also join PC

$∡Z'YP = ∡XYP $

$∡Z'AP=∡BAP=∡XCP$

It's easy to observe that PYXC is also cyclic

$∡XYP=∡XCP$
Hence, $∡Z'AP = ∡Z'YP$
And so, $ Z'=Z$ proved

Comment: Draw the figure so that $Z$ is on the ray $[BA$, but not on the segment $[BA]$. Then there are some issues with the above relations. In other words, the above rows depend on the chosen figure. Else: Please use mathjax to properly format the math symbols. Link: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference . So use `$ABC$` instead of `ABC` and so on.  The angles can be typed in a sample as `$\sphericalangle Z'YP$` which looks like $\sphericalangle Z'YP$. And which is the one question? Please state it explicitly.

Comment: I am extremely sorry for the mess, that spherical angle notation I have used is for directed angles...

Comment: This notation is not the problem. (Well it would have been nice to have a posted question using mathjax, but somebody will edit the question soon...) The main problem i have is as follows. Draw a picture so that $P$ is on the arc $\overset\frown{AC}$ and so that the projection $Z$ (which a posteriori is also $Z'$) of $P$ on $AB$ is not inside the segment $AB$, but where $X$ is in the segment $BC$, and $Y$ is in the segment $AC$. Then the relation $$\widehat{Z'YP}=\widehat{XYP}$$is not valid (in general). So the proof depends on the picture. (Inserting a picture is a good idea in such cases.)

Comment: But I don't get it, then how can such a quadrilateral ABPC be cyclic...Please give a better example

Comment: And also, may be there is something wrong with my proof or maybe there's a confusion as I cannot post a diagram, but the statement that you made cannot be correct, I guess...since it is a proof of Simson's line, right

Comment: OK, in order to have here a quick finish, please state explicitly a question. (This is a questions and answers site.) When the question is stated and clear, i will answer it, there is much more space in the answers field.

Comment: I have tried my best to make it as simple and explicit as possible, please check it now...